# Replace pattern in string PHP REGEX

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a string that is used for an `INSERT` command. When values are empty, the corresponding spot in the `INSERT` string is being generated as:

```
VALUES ('', 'VALUE', '', '', '', 0, 1, '')
```

I want to replace the '' with `NULL` so the database no longer throws an error about casting `varchar` to type `numeric`:

```
VALUES (null, 'VALUE', null, null, null, 0, 1, null)
```

I tried using:

```
$build_values_m = str_replace($build_values_m, ", '', ", ", null, ");
```

However, that takes away most of my `INSERT` string and does not JUST replace the empty values with `NULL`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to replace `"''"` with `"NULL"`? That is not what your `str_replace` is attempting to do (not even close).

Comment: @kainaw, yes if my string is VALUES('','VALUE','','','',0,1,'') I want it to say VAULES(null,'VALUE',null,null,null,0,1,null)

Comment: How you create string like `('','','VALUE HERE','',)`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to replace `"''"` with `"NULL"` and that you are attempting to do so without glancing at the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

If you looked at the manual, you would see that the order of the parameters is Search, Replace, OriginalString. You are trying to do OriginalString, Search, Replace - which won't work - obviously. So, try to do it in the proper order:

```
$build_values_m = str_replace("''","NULL",$build_values_m);
```

Then, all instances of `"''"` will be replaced with the string `"NULL"`.

Comment: @kainawa - so very sorry, it's too early here I wasn't thinking properly.  You are correct I had the arguments of str_replace mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform replacement using regex replacement function [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php) like following :

```
$string = "VALUES ('','','VALUE HERE','',)";
$pattern = array();
$pattern[0] = '/\'\'/g'; // Match : ''
$replacement = array();
$replacement[0] = 'NULL';

preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: this does work however kainaw pointed out first that I was calling str_replace incorrectly.  Thank you for your answer though!